# Can we define a variable as $rootScope and $scope at same controller

Tags: angularjs

Can we define a variable as $rootScope and $scope at same controller

```
$scope.Account=[{'sdfdsf','sdfds'}];
$scope.refreshAccountSummary = function () {
    Report.account(function (res) {
        $rootScope.Account = res.accountDetails;
    }
};
```

Comment: do you mean `$rootScope` instead of  `$routeScope` ?

Comment: yes u can. Should u? no.

Comment: no sorry spelling mistake here, I mean Can we use a variable as $rootScope and $scope.

Comment: spouse i have a var $scope.abc=10; can i update this with  $rootScope.abc =20 ?

Comment: Please edit your post if it's spelling mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, but its redundant.

$rootScope is kind of a global variable that is shared by all the controllers, hence if you are updating the $rootScope, the need to update the $scope variable of the same name is unnecessary.

Also its a bad practice to use $rootScope.

If you need a variable to be used in another scope try passing the variables through the services or factories.

Comment: I know very well difference between $rootScope and $scope and its use. But now I have different types of problem. I have a variable $scope.abc=10; and Can abc value is update with $rootscope.abc=20.

Comment: yes it can be. if you use $rootScope.abc=20 the scope variable abc will be updated to 20